# python - editing csv by adding chars to each row

Tags: python

I've got this dataset in a .csv file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2kzpzkhoiolhnlc/output.csv?dl=0

```
19,3,12
3
12
16,4
26,15,8,3
2
8
15
20
12,25,20,2,16
12,16
12,25
2,16
1,12
16,4
11,19,25,20
11,20,16,21
25,20,21
.....
```

for each row, if numbers are less then 51 than I need to add ? until having 51 chars in that row. For example, in the first row I have 19,3,12, so I have to add 48 ? to have a row like this: `19,3,12,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?`
In the second row I have just one number, so I have to add 50 ?, the same for the other rows. Could you help me please?

EDIT: I've tried with this but didn't work, it just added "" to some rows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('output.csv', sep=';')
df = df.fillna('?')
df.to_csv('sorted2.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: You mean columns, not characters, right?

Comment: can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: Anyway, you do this the same way you do anything else with CSV files. Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to open a reader on the input file and a writer on the output file. Then just loop over `for row in reader:`, extend the row out to length 51, and write it to the writer.

Comment: Or, if you want to use Pandas, its [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) automatically fills in missing columns, and you can specify the missing value to use, or convert it from `NaN` after reading.

Comment: @abarnert I've tried with read_csv but didn't work, I've added the code to the first post

Comment: Why are you passing `sep=';'` when your sample data has commas, not semicolons?

Comment: Anyway, I can't reproduce your problem. Your code as written raises an exception when trying to read the CSV file. If I fix that, the `fillna` works exactly as expected. Please give us a [mcve] that actually demonstrates your problem if you want us to debug it.

Comment: And if your code _didn't_ raise an exception, the wrong `sep` would mean you read one giant column, and then append 50 `?` columns onto every row. But if you fix _both_ of those problems, then… [see repl.it for a working example](https://repl.it/repls/FixedKookyComputer).

Comment: i fixed it and it works well with your code, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with just text file manipulation if you want, no need to use pandas or csv module for this simple case.

```
import csv
with open('source.csv') as f:
    with open('result.csv', 'w') as fw:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip() + (',?' * (50 - line.count(',')))
            fw.write(line + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas to read the file in and set the number of columns you want. The following code reads in a file and assigns n columns. The extra elements will by default have value np.nan

```
df.read_csv('file', names=range(n))
```

If you want them to have a different value you can assign it with

```
df.fillna(value, inplace = True)
```

Then you can just write the dataframe back into the file and it will have the shape you want

```
df.to_csv('file')
```

Comment: Sorry, I was meaning about columns, I should have 51 columns and not 51 rows! And I've added the code I've tried in the first post

Comment: @Nicola I had a typo in my answer which I have fixed, my code will make 51 columns. Also in your added code you use `sep = ";"` but your csv file uses `sep = ","` which is the read_csv default